# somehow the arrays did not work. Not storing any values and names when user input

Tags: c#

The program is to ask user input player last name and number for that player. The maximum of user can input players is 5. Using arrays to store.

```
namespace While_loop_testing
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        //Maximum number of players on a team (physical array size)
          const int MAX_PLAYERS = 5;
        //Array of player numbers
        int[] playerNumbers = new int[MAX_PLAYERS];
        //Corresponding array of player last names
        string[] playerLastNames = new string[MAX_PLAYERS];
        //Actual numbers of players currently in the roster (logical array size)
        int playerCount = 0;

        char item = 'o';

        while (item == 'I' || item == 'D' || item == 'R' || item != 'X')
        {
            item = ReadMenuOption();

            if (item == 'X')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thanks! GoodBye!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Prompt user for the input item
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>package</returns>
    static char ReadMenuOption()
    {
        char item;
        int MAX_PLAYERS = 25;
        int[] playerNumbers = new int[MAX_PLAYERS];
        string[] playerLastNames = new string[MAX_PLAYERS];
        int playerCount = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Options \n I - Insert Player \n D - Delete Player \n R - Player Report \n X - Exit Program");

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter item here : ");
            item = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper()[0];
            if (item == 'I')
            {
                ProcessInsert(playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerCount, MAX_PLAYERS);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            else if (item == 'D')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ProcessDeleteCalled");
                Console.WriteLine("");

            }
            else if (item == 'R')
            {
                ProcessReport(playerNumbers,playerLastNames, playerCount);
                Console.WriteLine("");

            }
            else if (item != 'I' && item != 'D' && item != 'R' && item != 'X')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid option. Please enter again");
                Console.WriteLine("");

            }
        } while (item != 'I' && item != 'D' && item != 'R' && item != 'X');
        return item;
    }
    static void ProcessInsert(int[] playerNumbers, string[] playerLastNames, int playerCount, int MAX_PLAYERS)
    {
        int numberOfPlayer, insertIndex, count;
        string prompt = "Enter player number here : ";
        string prompt1 = "Enter player Last Name here : ";
        string name;
        char response;

        if (playerCount < MAX_PLAYERS)
        {
            numberOfPlayer = GetPosNonZeroInt(prompt);
            insertIndex = GetInsertIndex(numberOfPlayer, playerNumbers, playerCount);
            if (insertIndex == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" The player number is already exists");
            }
            else
            {
                name = GetNonEmptyString(prompt1);
                for (count = playerCount; count > insertIndex; count--)
                {
                    playerNumbers[count] = playerNumbers[count - 1];
                    playerLastNames[count] = playerLastNames[count - 1];
                }
                playerCount++;
                playerLastNames[insertIndex] = name;
                numberOfPlayer = playerNumbers[insertIndex];

            }
            if (playerCount == MAX_PLAYERS)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nThe player roster is now full");
            }
            else
            {
                response = GetUpperYNChar("\nWould you like to insert another");
                if (response == 'N')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you!!!");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe player roster is already full");
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="prompt"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static int GetPosNonZeroInt(string prompt)
    {
        int numberOfPlayer;
        do
        {
            Console.Write(prompt);
            numberOfPlayer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (numberOfPlayer <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid numbers");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a positive numbers");
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        } while (numberOfPlayer < 0);
        return numberOfPlayer;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="playerNumber"></param>
    /// <param name="playerNumbers"></param>
    /// <param name="playerCount"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static int GetInsertIndex(int playerNumber, int[] playerNumbers, int playerCount)
    {
        int insertIndex = 0;
        bool found = false;
        while (insertIndex < playerCount && found == false)
        {
            if (playerNumbers[insertIndex] == playerNumber)
            {
                insertIndex = -1;
                found = true;
            }
            else if (playerNumbers[insertIndex] > playerNumber)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                insertIndex = insertIndex + 1;
            }
        }
        return insertIndex;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="playerNumbers"></param>
    /// <param name="playerLastNames"></param>
    /// <param name="playerCount"></param>
    static void ProcessReport(int[] playerNumbers, string[] playerLastNames, int playerCount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Player Number    Player Last Name");
        for (int counter = 0; counter < playerCount; counter++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("           {0}                  {1}", playerNumbers[counter], playerLastNames[counter]);
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="prompt"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static string GetNonEmptyString(string prompt)
    {
        string str;
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write(prompt);
        str = Console.ReadLine();
        while (str == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error - input must not be empty");
            Console.Write(prompt);
            str = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return str;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="prompt"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static char GetUpperYNChar(string prompt)
    {
        char YN;
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        YN = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        YN = Char.ToUpper(YN);
        Console.ReadKey();
        while (YN != 'Y' && YN != 'N')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid Response - Please Enter Y OR N");
            YN = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            YN = Char.ToUpper(YN);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        return Char.ToUpper(YN);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a tool named Debugger that allows you to follow your code step by step. Try to use it, you will discover where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you change the `playerCount` parameter in the `ProcessInsert` method, it will not affect the variable outside the method. Parameters are sent by value, so the parameter `playerCount` has a copy of the value from the `playerCount` variable outside the method.

To make the parameter reference the variable, you need the `ref` keyword:

```
static void ProcessInsert(int[] playerNumbers, string[] playerLastNames, ref int playerCount, int MAX_PLAYERS)
```

You also need to use if in every place you call the method:

```
ProcessInsert(playerNumbers, playerLastNames, ref playerCount, MAX_PLAYERS);
```

---

You are getting a value from the array instead of putting a value in it. This line:

```
numberOfPlayer = playerNumbers[insertIndex];
```

should be:

```
playerNumbers[insertIndex] = numberOfPlayer;
```

Comment: I did add the ref to playerCount, but still the the arrays did not store the numbers and names in the array

Comment: @SivoBass: I added another bug above.